# Batch normalization : fixed samples or different samples by dimension?

Tags: deep-learning, batch-normalization

Some questions came to me as I read a paper 'Batch Normalization : Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift'.

In the paper, it says:

Since m examples from training data can estimate mean and variance of all training data, we use mini-batch to train batch normalization parameters.

My question is :

Are they choosing m examples and then fitting batch norm parameters concurrently, or choosing different set of m examples for each input dimension?

e.g. training set is composed of x(i) = (x1,x2,...,xn) : n-dimension for fixed batch M = {x(1),x(2),...,x(N)}, perform fitting all gamma1~gamman and beta1~betan.

vs

for gamma_i, beta_i picking different batch M_i = {x(1)_i,...,x(m)_i}

Comment: Maxim posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501088/batch-normalization-fixed-samples-or-different-samples-by-dimension/46609935#46609935).